# R, dplyr package, get a closing value for each day

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have the following data (df) for a month:

```
        timestamp      symbol side size  price
1: 2021-01-01 00:00:01 XBTUSD  Buy 10000 28951.0
2: 2021-01-01 00:00:05 XBTUSD Sell     1 28950.5
3: 2021-01-01 00:00:06 XBTUSD Sell     1 28950.5
4: 2021-01-01 00:00:06 XBTUSD Sell     1 28950.5
5: 2021-01-01 00:00:06 XBTUSD Sell     1 28950.5
6: 2021-01-01 00:00:07 XBTUSD Sell     1 28950.5
7:   ...        ...     ...   ...   ...   ...
```

And I want to extract the closing price for each trading day. I use the following code:

```
cl_price <- df %>% mutate(day = day(timestamp)) %>% 
      group_by(day) %>% summarise(closing = last(price))
```

However, it gives not a vector of closing prices for each day, but only one closing price which corresponds to the last day of the month. Here's the output:

```
closing
1   33101
```

How can I modify the code above, so I receive a vector of closing prices for each trading day within a month, but not only the last one?
Thank you!

**Sample Data**

```
structure(list(timestamp = c("2021-01-01 00:00:01", "2021-01-01 00:00:05", 
"2021-01-01 00:00:06", "2021-01-01 00:00:06", "2021-01-01 00:00:06", 
"2021-01-01 00:00:07"), symbol = c("XBTUSD", "XBTUSD", "XBTUSD", 
"XBTUSD", "XBTUSD", "XBTUSD"), side = c("Buy", "Sell", "Sell", 
"Sell", "Sell", "Sell"), size = c(10000, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), price = c(28951, 
28950.5, 28950.5, 28950.5, 28950.5, 28950.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I only use the first 6 rows of your sample data for this solution but bear in mind that in order for your question to attract relevant result you need to share a reproducible piece of your data by means of `dput(head(data))` so that people can use it to help you and have a clearer idea of your data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the following solution. I also think there may be a more concise solution for this but for you it will do the trick:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(timestamp = ymd_hms(timestamp)) %>%
  mutate(year = year(timestamp), 
         month = month(timestamp), 
         day = day(timestamp)) %>% 
  group_by(year, month, day) %>%
  arrange(year, month, day) %>%
  slice_tail() %>%
  pull(price)

[1] 28950.5
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(timestamp = c("2021-01-01 00:00:01", "2021-01-01 00:00:05", 
"2021-01-01 00:00:06", "2021-01-01 00:00:06", "2021-01-01 00:00:06", 
"2021-01-01 00:00:07"), symbol = c("XBTUSD", "XBTUSD", "XBTUSD", 
"XBTUSD", "XBTUSD", "XBTUSD"), side = c("Buy", "Sell", "Sell", 
"Sell", "Sell", "Sell"), size = c(10000, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), price = c(28951, 
28950.5, 28950.5, 28950.5, 28950.5, 28950.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```